# Retrieving object from NSMutableArray based on key value of child NSMutableDictonary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, search, nsmutablearray

So I have an `NSMutableArray` in my app what is filled like so:

```
NSMutableArray
--Object 1 (NSMutableDictonary)
  --Value (i) for key (key)
  --Value (i) for key (key)
--Object 2 (NSMutableDictonary)
  --Value (i) for key (key)
  --Value (i) for key (key)
```

i need to be able to select an object from within the main `NSMutableArray` by looking for a key what matches a value of one of the `NSMutableDictonary`'s keys...

I understand i could run a loop like so to achieve this:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *object in arrayObject) {
    if ([[object objectForKey:@"keyToSearch"] integerValue] == keyToCompare) {
        return [object objectForKey:@"keyToReturn"];
    }
}
```

However my concern is that if this array grows (what it can do) then this will take time to run a search on it..

So I was wondering is there any other way to retrieve the same results but more efficiently?

Thanks

Liam

Comment: Unless you can somehow map keys to the array's indexes, there isn't really a faster way other than iterating through the entire array looking for your key.

One other way you could do it is to use another NSMutableDictionary to store your dictionaries and use every key from your low level dictionary as keys for the entire dictionary. That way, you could just ask for the object (dictionary) for a key you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search is obviously going to take linear time in the number of dictionaries in the array. You're not going to get around that by using a different way to search. You could rewrite your search to use an `NSPredicate`, and it would be slightly shorter but it wouldn't be any faster.

If you want to make the search faster, you'll have to modify your data structure. Or, you could create a `NSDictionary` to serve as a lookup table, where the keys of the `NSDictionary` are values of `keyToSearch`, and the values are the `NSMutableDictionaries` in your array.

Still, unless your array gets really really, big the search time will be negligible, and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, I decided that what you said was probably the easiest thing to do so I adapted my datasource and then if i wanted to use it like an array still i could call [dicDataSource allKeys] to get an array of the keys and then loop through them as if it was an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, any enumeration of any array will take time that grows as the size of the array grows. If you have any way to hint at the location of it, it may make it faster, but otherwise, Fast Enumeration is probably the fastest way to run through the data in the way that you want to.

Unless you run through hundreds of objects, the time taken should be negligible.